# How do I address an incomplete masters degree on resume

Tags: resume, graduate

I am currently applying to jobs and I have finished all the coursework for my masters, but failed masters thesis. How do I put this on my resume? Do I put all but thesis? I know I can't leave it of my resume, since then there will be a two year gap after my undergraduate school.

Comment: Do you have a diploma or actively working towards finishing? Or did you drop out?

Comment: With an active degree, you should just put the expected graduate date. If you completely dropped out, you can put you completed your masters courses, but not the thesis.

Comment: What was the specific outcome of your thesis review? Revisions suggested, or completely rejected? If the latter, do you have the opportunity to present something new, or is the entire program a loss?

Comment: @jcmack please don't answer in comments, post an answer instead :)

Comment: @DarkCygnus I was waiting for more information, but I can convert my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 1):

With an active degree, you should just put the expected graduate date.

If you completely dropped out of the degree program, you can put you completed your masters courses, but not the thesis. This is actually fairly common for people who dropped out of their PhD programs.